# Entity Framework select and exclude field from Entity class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In EF this query gives me anonymous class `List<anonymous{}>`.Is there an other way to get result as `List<Parent>`. Or Is there a way to exclude properties in `select` from parent and child class

```
db<Parent>
      .Select(o => new { o.ID, Childs = o.Childs.Select(t => new { t.ID }) })
      .ToList()
```

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/171858).  I'm down-voting this until you describe why you believe you need this feature.  (Then I'll most likely up-vote it).

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ to SQL - How to select specific columns and return strongly typed list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094931/linq-to-sql-how-to-select-specific-columns-and-return-strongly-typed-list)

Comment: @ErikPhilips: Kinda disagree. The problem is that it's returning an anonymous object instead of the strongly typed one. Does he really need to go into his reasons for wanting to do that? Isn't this more of a black and white Q&A site?

Comment: @MikeCole it's definitely not black and white.  I'd recommend reading the what an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/171858) is.  Many, many.. so many questions ask about why a particular regex statement doesn't work, when the answer doesn't even need regex to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, project it into a Parent object instead of an anonymous object.

```
db<Parent>
.Select(o =>
       new Parent{ o.ID,
                   Childs = o.Childs.Select(t => new { t.ID })
                 }
       ).ToList();
```

On second thought:
If you're not returning every property with the Parent class, [opinion alert] you should project instead into a DTO because then you have to manage/remember which fields are being loaded and which aren't. That's a maintenance nightmare. [/opinion alert]

Comment: But at this time references in Child to Parent object will be `null`

Comment: Assuming `Parent` has a parameterless ctor and doesn't come from a [protected] POCO lib. ;; Follow-up to `[opinion]`, depending on scale (and frequency [the OP] is doing this), something like AutoMapper may be worthwhile to look at.

Comment: @Horizon, IMHO you're fighting the ORM too much. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify an environment in which you need this behavior but it's common in MVC.

If you're asking about MVC then it's likely you need to serialize to json your result.

If that's the case and creating specific selects for complicated cases then...

(I know - lots of IFs, my answer may not be applicable, but still :)

... look at [custom ContractResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543385/where-should-i-plug-in-my-custom-defaultcontractresolver-json-net/24580859#24580859) implementation.

Answer (score 0):

> Or Is there a way to exclude properties in select from parent and child class.

*No*, you cannot select/return a strongly-typed Entity Framework object and at the same time exclude the properties of said object.